# Cooper pair attractive power in lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics, superconductivity

In Kittel's book of Solid State Physics, it is said that, whenever an electron passes the positive ion core in the lattice, it has the ability to distort the lattice s.t by attracting the positive ion cores. Does the attraction has to do anything to the mass of an electron, as being small, does it posses the attractive power to make the nearby positive ion cores to pull toward that electron, as positive ion cores are much heavier.

Answer (score 1):

The attraction has nothing to do with the electron mass. It is the negative charge of the electron that attracts the positive ions. However, the mass of the electrons plays a role in the dynamics. As it is much lighter, it moves faster than ions vibrate, assuming equal energy distribution.

The electron attracts the ions and goes away quickly. The ions "slowly" moves towards each other and create a local positive-charged region, which can attract another electron. This is the "hand-waving" description of the so-called "retarded-interaction" between the two electrons that form a Cooper pair.